# дублируються данные когда передаю в json

Tags: javascript

у меня есть n количество табов, с которых нужно собрать данные но проблема в том что если в первом у нас doc 1, doc 2, а во втором doc 3, doc 4 - То результат при сохранении получаеться в первом табе doc 1, doc 2, doc 3, doc 4 а во втором doc 1, doc 2, doc 3, doc 4 как это можно исправить?
html:

```
<div id="eventItems">
<div data-section-name="document" id="20">
   <div class="cd__item"><div class="cd__item-name"><span>doc 1</span></div></div>
   <div class="cd__item"><div class="cd__item-name"><span>doc 2</span></div></div>
</div>
<div data-section-name="document" id="49">
   <div class="cd__item"><div class="cd__item-name"><span>doc 3</span></div></div>
   <div class="cd__item"><div class="cd__item-name"><span>doc 4</span></div></div>
</div>
<button>save</button>
</div>


js:
$("button").click(function() {
var event = [],
    objEvent = {},
    customDocsEvent = [];

$('#eventItems').find("[data-section-name='document']").each(function() {
                $(this).find(".cd__item").each(function() {
                    var name = $(this).find(".cd__item-name").find("span").text()

                    customDocsEvent.push({
                        name: name
                    });
                });

                if (customDocsEvent.length) {
                    $('#eventItems').find("[data-section-name='document']").each(function() {
                        var idSection = $(this).attr("id");
                        objEvent = {
                            "type" : "document",
                            "id" : idSection,
                            "content" : customDocsEvent
                        };
                        event.push(objEvent);
                    });
                }
            });

            var elements = [
                {
                    "section" : "event",
                    "data" : event
                }
            ];


            elements = JSON.stringify(elements);
            console.log(elements);
});
```

Comment: `.find("span")` - ??

Comment: span то я в примере забыл просто написать, поправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В коде один и тот же массив `customDocsEvent` во всех `objEvent`.

   ```
   $('#eventItems').find("[data-section-name='document']").each(function() {
     customDocsEvent = []; // !!!
     ...
   ```
2. Уберите внутренний цикл по `$('#eventItems').find("[data-section-name='document']")` - он не нужен.

Comment: нет, не работает, всё также дублирует когда сделал как в вашем примере

Comment: @DimaVleskov Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код. Попробуйте еще раз.